# Windows, .NET reading text under mouse cursor

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible to get the text under mouse cursor from a window by a program working in background?

Comment: In general, no, text is just pixels.  But most quality code supports accessibility, used by screen readers for users with visual impairments.  Not very well documented for C#, google the IAccessible interface.

Comment: Use the classes in the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using P/Ivoke. Some pointers:

- [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ChildWindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I think you have to do a attach to thread input to be allowed to read the text from a control of another process.

Comment: Looks very promising, but there is one problem. GetWindowText returns the text of the specified window's title bar, while I need the text from under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the mouse cursor position and a screenshot and then just read the pixels from the screenshot near the cursor.

Hardest part in this solution is recognizing the text from picture but there should be libraries for that somewhere.

Comment: It's not a solution I'm looking for. Maybe I'll consider this if there is nothing better, but still hope there is.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go to far down this path, have a look at AutoIt. There is a tool called "AutoIt Window Info" that will tell you if any of the Win32 libraries can see text in the window selected. If you can't see text there, then I would suggest that you use `ManagedWinapi.dll`, capture the window handle, use the Image property of the returned `SystemWindow` class and send that to an OCR library.